Strange error while building Flutter project using android_alarm_manager_plus
I created an empty Flutter project, added android_alarm_manager_plus to pubspec.yaml, but when I try to build app, I receive this error :
Note: C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\android_alarm_manager_plus-4.0.4\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\AlarmService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
ERROR:C:\Users\ALEX\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c1a2b6b5561495bcbfc5c4cf26e6c722\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR:C:\Users\ALEX\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\db2a3820c5429822d426817c25731a6c\transformed\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-resources-1.7.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\ALEX\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c1a2b6b5561495bcbfc5c4cf26e6c722\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.7.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\ALEX\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\db2a3820c5429822d426817c25731a6c\transformed\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


try to make sure that you have met all requirement from android_alarm_manager_plus

If it still can't build you can try to enable multiDex in build.gradle in module level
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}

ref : https://developer.android.com/build/multidex#mdex-gradle
Hope this will help
